# How to download iOS app archive from Azure DevOps?

Tags: ios, azure-devops

I have a pipeline in Azure DevOps for publishing app to App Store. I need the produced archive to get dSYM files from it. How do I setup the pipeline to get an archive after the pipeline is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the builded archive directly from the UI.

Select the successful build from your build history. On the top right corner of the build logs page. You can click the **artifacts** and download published artifacts.
[image]

You can aslo add a powershell task at the end of your pipeline to download the artifacts using [restful API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get%20artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#artifactresource).

```
curl -u $AZURE_USERNAME:$AZURE_TOKEN "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/$SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT/_apis/build/builds/$BUILD_BUILDID/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=4.1")
```

**Update:**

to include dSYM file in the artifacts, you can add a **Copy Files task** before the **Publish build Artifact task**, For blow example, in this way the dSYM file will be copied to dSYM folder of the artifacts.

[image]

Comment: I can only download .ipa file from there. May be you can add instructions to properly configure pipeline for your answer to be full?

Comment: did not work. I made it like this https://ibb.co/BgV5c60
It actually saves ipa, but not dSYM or xcarchive

Comment: Found out the issue, will post it as another answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Levi did not work for me. But it was pretty close.

I guess first of all it should not be `**/.dSYM`, but `**/*.dSYM`.

But it still did not save it, what I did was put `**` which will save everything, then start the pipeline and collect the artifacts. Then I found where was the `xcarchive` file located, it was right in the root folder.

So I guess the problem was that it was in the root folder. Did not check yet, but I guess `**.xcarchive` will work. You can find `dSYM` files there.

**Update**

Even `**.xcarchive` did not work for me. Only `**` works. Don't know why.

Comment: I was working on a similar problem. I think the problem might be, that .xcarchive is not a file but a directory. So to publish it, you should use the task ArchiveFiles (instead of Copyfiles) and create a .zip from the .xcarchive directory. Output that zip to $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)

Comment: none of the mentioned approaches worked for me..